# get login and password admin of farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm developping a user interface with the intent to connect to my farm.
I wonder if there is any cmd powershell to get login and password admin or there is other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is powershell script to retirve the password but you have to know the farm admin account in advance.

[Retrieve SharePoint Managed Accounts Password](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/Retrieve-SharePoint-Managed-Accounts-Password.aspx)

this is good tool from CodePlex for recovery the services account details, you can take a look on the Code...may help you for the piece you looking for.

[SharePoint Service Account Password Recovery Tool](http://spcracker.codeplex.com/)